# dumping larg database backup or splitting large sql files into smaller parts to dump

Tags: mysql, database, split, database-backups, large-data

I have a backup file from a big database. its about 85Mb in gzip format and 1.5Gb in sql format.

Now I want to import it in my local database. but no phpMyadmin and nor Naicat for Mysql can't do it. So i want an application to split it to smaller parts and import it part by part. 
I tryed notepad++, glogg and TSE Pro ti read and manually split, but except TSE others couldn't open it and TSE hangs after selecting and cutting 10000 line of text.

I also tried Gsplit to split it but it seems Gsplit has it's own type for split-ed parts that isn't txt.

thanks for your help. your help may contain any other solution to restore my db in local...

Comment: try bigdump http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/ or you can check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20446203/2246798

Comment: 1+ thanks @souvickcse bigdump worked great and solved my problem

Comment: You can upvote my previous answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to    @souvickcse the [bigdump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) worked great.